# Problemas al incrementar un contador en una función recursiva?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, recursión

Tengo una duda acerca de la funcionalidad de incrementar valores dentro de una función recursiva.

Cuando uso:

`counter++` no funciona

Pero cuando uso `counter + 1` Funciona correctamente.

También encontré otra forma para que funcione: `++counter`, pero la verdad no logré entender bien que diferencia tiene usar el ++ antes del counter.

Ejemplo:

```
printEachName = (companyNames, newPeople, counter, callback) => {
  if (companyNames.length === newPeople.length) {
    return callback(false, companyNames);
  }
  console.log('counter >>> ', counter);
  let newP = newPeople[counter];

  companyNames.push(newP.name);
  printEachName(companyNames, newPeople, counter + 1, callback);
}

printEachName([], newPeople, 0, (errorPrinting, response) => {
      if (errorPrinting) {
        //res.send()
        return;
      }

      console.log('response is >>> ', response);
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dentro del tema de las expresiones autoincrementables tenemos dos casos a considerar los cuales tú ya expusiste en tu pregunta:

- Caso **i++**: aquí la expresión regresa el valor de `i` antes de que este aumente de valor, y después de regresar el valor, aumenta en 1.

```js
var i = 40;

alert (i++) //Alerta 40
alert(i) //Alerta 41
```

- Caso **++i**: Aquí es el caso contrario, primero aumenta en uno el valor y después regresa el valor.

```js
var j = 40;

alert(++j); //alerta 41
alert(j); //alerta 41
```

La razón por la cual no te funciona con `contador++` es porque a la función le está mandando el valor de `contador` antes de que este aumente, es por eso que `++contador` o `contador+1` te funciona correctamente.